# How to declare variable in setting.gradle.kts and use it in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle

If I understand it correctly settings is red first and builds later, so it should be possible but cannot figure it out.

I tried in setting:

```
gradle.extra.properties["platform_version"] = "0.0.10"
```

but in bild

```
println(gradle.extra.properties["platform_version"])
```

outputs `null`

EXTEND:

I have multi module project using

```
includeBuild("../module1")
includeBuild("../module2")
```

and I need to get the property do all  submodules. I also tried

```
val rootPlatformVersion = "foo"
subprojects.forEach {
    println("module $it")
    it.gradle.extra["platformVersion"] = rootPlatformVersion
}
```

but it seems, it's not working with includeBuild, because included builds are processed before main project

I expect passing value should be trivial ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you set value directly on `extra` extension.

in settings.gradle.kts

```
gradle.extra["platform_version"] = "0.0.10"
```

in build.gradle.kts you read it as

```
println(gradle.extra["platform_version"])
```

Documentation on [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html#N1B920) class says

> Returns all of the registered properties and their current values as a map. The returned map is detached from the extension.

That probably means that when you use .properties method you get a map instance that isn't bound to gradle object and you won't be able to reference values in build.gradle.kts script.

**Composite builds**

You use includeBuild - that means you are using composite builds. Here each project evaluates its own settings.gradle.kts file. Gradle object and its properties won't be propagated from main project to the included one.

Depends on the use case you could:

A) Configure **global properties** file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and just read normal properties in the projects `project.extra["platform_version"]`

B) If you still for some reason need those extra properties on Gradle object there is **global settings/init** script that always gets executed for all projects you run. Add into `~/.gradle/init.gradle.kts` your dependency version `gradle.extra["platform_version"] = "0.0.10"`

C) Cleanest approach from my PoV is to have another project that produces **BOM/Platform** a list of dependencies and their versions which is referenced in both of your other projects. In your projects you don't explicitly define versions but resolve versions from BOM. You would need to change version only in BOM project.[BOM](https://medium.com/mwm-io/generate-bill-of-material-bom-with-maven-publish-plugin-f30b44ab5436) or [Version catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html)

Comment: well, that works except multi module project

Comment: Are you referring to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html multi-project build or https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html composed build?

Comment: And why are you even setting extra properties on `gradle` object? I would rely on standard properties. If you need to set global properties set them in your home gradle directory and they will be picked up in composite builds. `~/.gradle/gradle.properties.` then in your build.gradle files reference them as `project.extra["platform_version"]`.

Comment: Or if you insist on adding extra property on gradle object then you have to set it on global `~/.gradle/init.gradle.kts` script as `gradle.extra["platform_version"] = "0.0.10"`. This value will be picked up by all the composite builds, while you can overwrite it in the settings.gradle.kts file of a particular project or in the project itself. You can't set it in root composite project and force all other projects to take it form there.

Comment: At the end those are two separate projects. Fix the version in other project directly and don't try to propagate properties form one separate project to other if you use composed builds. Use multiproject build instead if this is one artifact and one module can't be used without another. Probably another thing you could do is to use third project that produces BOM/platform that is then used in other projects (if you have 10 or more dependencies that you would need to align).

Comment: Thank you for composite build explanation. I didn't know that. I'm trying to implement version C, I have already BOM platform project implemented by all my projects. The platform needs to be versioned too. New platform version needs to be put into other projects, so it create new project versions, then the platform should use them and that create new platform version. That is why i want to have one place to declare platform version in one place only.

Comment: Also, it's all git projects, so all needs to versioned. Therefore nothing should go to user $HOME. I'm trying to convert platform project to catalog